# ServicFabric remoting from Asp.Net MVC webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-service-fabric

I'm having trouble calling my SF service method via remoting from a Asp.Net MVC webapplication.

```
var myServiceProxy = ServiceProxy
   .Create<IMyService>("fabric:/MyCompany.MyServiceFabricApp/MyService");
myServiceProxy.MyServiceProxyMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

With `MyServiceProxyMethodAsync` calling `IMyService.MyServiceMethodAsync` in the `ServiceFabric` MyService. This call just does nothing !

Running the same code from a console application works fine.
I'm having everything x64 and running IISExpress in 64bit.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe your problem is that you are passing in a string. The example on their website shows that they are passing a URI: `IMyService helloWorldClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IMyService>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApplication/MyHelloWorldService"));`

Comment: Besides that, `myServiceProxy.MyServiceProxyMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` probably gives a return value. You aren't doing anything with it. Try `var result = myServiceProxy.MyServiceProxyMethodAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: If it aren't those two things, you might want to add the code from the function `myServiceProxy.MyServiceProxyMethodAsync()` to your question. I can't replicate your problem on my machine because not all the code is provided.

Comment: Can you get a breakpoint to hit on the service you are calling? Are you running this all locally?